# Check Array and Hash is Empty or Not

Tags: perl

I have an array and hash. I just want to check whether they both are empty or not.

I found below two methods to check this. Any suggestion which would be more suffice.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @a = qw/a b c/; 
print Dumper(\@a);

my %b = (1 => "Hi");
print Dumper(\%b);

@a = ();
%b = ();

#Method 1
if(!@a && !%b){
    print "Empty\n";
} else {
    print "Not empty\n";
}

#Method 2
if(!scalar @a && !scalar keys %b){
    print "Empty\n";
} else {
    print "Not empty\n";
}
```

The case here is, either both would be Empty or both would have some values.

Comment: The `scalar` function is redundant when used in scalar context, which `&&` imposes.

Comment: Also, your entire question revolves around the phrase "more suffice". This phrase is incorrect. A thing that "suffices" is "enough". So "more enough" doesn't make sense. We can guess that you are asking "which is more efficient", or "which is better", and that question is in this case irrelevant, or premature optimization. You have two solutions that do the same thing.

Comment: I'd stick with method 1.

Comment: Better to use `and` instead of `&&`, or use parentheses to ensure correct precedence. Consider: `print "a" && "b"` vs. `print "a" and "b"`

Comment: @jhnc I disagree. `&&` has more or less the same precedence in Perl as in other languages (eg, C, C++, Java...), while `and` definitely doesn't have the precedence that people usually expect. Your `print` example makes little sense in both cases. If unclear precedence is an issue, using parenthesis should be the solution. I'm not sure I can think of a good use-case for `and` and `or` except `or die $!`.

Comment: @Dada PBP "low-precedence operators" agrees with you. However, consider what happens if you weren't using `scalar`: `sub f{1+@_} @a=(1); @b=(); say(f@a&&f@b); say(f(@a)&&f(@b)); say(f@a and f@b); say(f(@a) and f(@b))'`. I believe first case is actually parsed as `f(@a && f@b)` !

Comment: @jhnc, I disagree. `and` is usually best used for flow control (`and next`, `and return`, `and die`, etc), but `&&` is usually best otherwise.

Comment: @jhnc Re "*I believe first case is actually parsed as*", Yup, one of the many reasons why leaving out parens around args is problematic

Comment: @ikegami that's why I suggested `and [...], or parentheses`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For finding whether a hash or array is empty,

- **Hash empty-ness**: `(%hash)` and `(keys %hash)`, when used in a boolean context, are equally optimised internally, and have been since since perl 5.28.0. They both just examine the hash for non-emptiness and evaluate to a true or false value. Prior to that, it was much more complex, and changed across releases, that is to say `(keys %hash)` *may* have been faster, but this is no longer a concern.
- **Array empty-ness**: `@array` in scalar context has always been efficient, and will tell you whether the array is empty.

Comment: @ikegami [Dave Mitchell is a core contributor to Perl](https://news.perlfoundation.org/post/maintaining_perl5_dave_mitchell_mar_2022). I doubt the words I left intact are wrong, and if they are you can [edit] this answer to fix them. Agreeable, as in, interested in making the site better for everyone. Not just providing a new answer with more words.

Answer (score 3):

**Array**

Use `@a` in scalar context.

Examples:

```perl
say @a ? "not empty" : "empty";
```

```perl
@a 
   or die( "At least one value is required" );
```

```perl
my $num_elements = @a;
```

---

**Hash**

Use `%h` or `keys( %h )` in scalar context.

If the code will be run on older versions of Perl, you want `keys( %hash )` because `%h` was [inefficient before 5.26](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5260delta#scalar(%25hash)-return-signature-changed).

Examples:

```perl
say %h ? "not empty" : "empty";   # Slower before 5.26
```

```perl
say keys( %h ) ? "not empty" : "empty";
```

```perl
%h                                # Slower before 5.26
   or die( "At least one element is required" );
```

```perl
keys( %h )
   or die( "At least one element is required" );
```

```perl
my $has_elements = %h;            # Slower before 5.26
```

```perl
my $num_elements = %h;            # 5.26+
```

```perl
my $num_elements = keys( %h );
```

---

Note that `!@a` and `!scalar @a` are *identical* since `!` already imposes a scalar context. The same goes for `!scalar keys %b` and `!keys %b`.